# How do i create a OAuth 2.0 Client ID for desktop?

Tags: google-api

I do not even know where to ask this question so if it shouldnt be asked on stack overflow just say.

So i am trying to create a OAuth 2.0 client for DESKTOP WINDOWS like that kickstart example project prompts you to do, but if i try to create a new OAuth 2.0 client i get theese options :

-Web application

-Android

-Chrome App

-iOS

-Other

but no desktop option (like in the kickstart example), and because of that there is no way to auth the service (that i am aware of)